# Slowlog grok pattern?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok

[2016-12-28T15:53:21,341]

what is the logstash pattern for this ES 5.1.1 slowlog? I tried using the following timestamp [%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}] but this satisifies the above format to certain extent but not fully because 341 is missed.

Can anyone help in solving out this grok pattern?

Comment: can anyone say what is 341 in the above ES slowlog ?

Comment: 341 is the number of milliseconds and if you try it on http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ you'll see that 341 is matched too

Comment: so,u r saying that this timestamp is valid for the above slowlog

Comment: when i tried the above link which u had given i am getting a compile error where in input i given [2016-12-28T15:53:21,341] and pattern i given [%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}]

Comment: can u pls help me in solving this because i am new to this environment??

Comment: Oh, you need to escape the square brackets `\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logtime}\]`

Comment: yeah,thanku i need to remove both square brackets and also :logtime

Comment: sry no need remove :logtime,square brackets is enough

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out